# Orderby word in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table

```
id  name   status
---------------------
1   John   Approved
2   Kelly  Pending
3   Iva    Pending
5   Denis  Rejected
6   Michael Approved
```

I want to group & order in such a way that it shows Pending records first, Approved second & rejected last

Comment: That's just ordering, not grouping. Ordering puts records next to each other in a specific order, grouping combines multiple records into one (aggregation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY FIELD(`status`, 'Pending','Approved','Rejected')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c342/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added another case*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac23/2)

**SOURCE**

- [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)